# uget queue not auto-downloading

Tags: uget

I'm experimenting with some download managers on Ubuntu, and I think uget + aria2 is very good in terms of speed.

So I decided to make a queue and download those files using uget, with aria2 plugin enabled. However, the queue is not auto-downloading, ie the downloading stops after one file finishes. It should go to the next download automatically.

Note: What I want is to download a queue one by one (so I change the active download to one, one file at a time), not download them all at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not quite sure what your issue is but you need to edit the settings for whatever category you are using to limit the amount of active downloads at a time.

[1.] Right click the name of the Category and choose "Properties".

[image]

[2.] By default the settings will list "3 as the Active Downloads".

[image]

[3.] Change that to "1" and it should work like you want it to.

[image]

Comment: Right from the creator! Thanks a lot, for the answer & the software :D

Comment: Yep, I try my best to be attentive on these kinds of sites. :) Thanks for using our app, I'm glad you like it.

Comment: This just doesn’t work for me where I need it. Music downloads from Hyperion seem to need a “Force Start”, but if you Force Start all the downloads then that overrides the category choice about Active downloads.

Comment: A force start should override the setting because it is forcing the start despite the setting.  If the server doesn't support the usage of download managers requiring a force then that is unfortunate but not something that the app can solve as it is at a server level.